# Greying out multiple submit buttons upon submission of 1 using GetElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I am fairly new to JavaScript. My goal is to grey out all submit buttons on page for 30 seconds upon submission of one. I have multiple text-areas hence the multiple submit buttons. The first code works fine but I would have to write it 23 times in order to get my desired result. Is their a way to write the code one time but include all id's or any other code to get the same result?

```
// This works but I would have to write it 23 times, inserting the new id each rewrite
     <script type="text/javascript">
       setTimeout (function(){
       document.getElementById('news').disabled = null;
       },30000);
     </script>

//I have left out textarea for this example
<input id="news" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">

// This will not work, adding the extra id
     <script type="text/javascript">
       setTimeout (function(){
       document.getElementById('news', 'sports').disabled = null;
       },30000);
     </script>
//I have left out textarea for this example 
<input id="news" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">

//I have left out textarea for this example 
<input id="sports" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: try it by adding class to buttons..

Comment: Give them all a class and [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName). Then iterate through the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add classes to your buttons:

```
<input class="submit" id="news" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
<input class="submit" id="sports" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
```

and then you can do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('submit');
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].disabled = null;
    }
}, 30000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Jw5n/

Comment: Thank you adding a class to each does in fact do exactly what I was shooting for. P.S. 30 seconds is 30000 :)

Comment: @posh2.0: Yes, I know. For the purpose of my fiddle, I wasn't going to wait 30 seconds. Feel free to put in whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

As you have jquery as tag, you could do this:

```
  setTimeout (function(){
      $("input").each(function(){
           $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      })
   },30000);
```

You could also add a class to all your inputs and use `$(".class").each(function(){` instead

Comment: I am going to implement this and get back

Comment: I am sorry juvian, but I have to give credit where credit is due. Your code did grey out all submission buttons but not upon the submission of one button. Matt Burlands does exactly what I was asking, he just put for 3 seconds instead of 30. Thank you very much for the input though!

Comment: @posh2.0 the only difference I notice is the 3 seconds instead of 30 and I had though you wanted to grey them out, if you want to enable them again as matt does, you need to use `$(this).prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: Yes, but on the event of a user submitting, then have the 30 second delay on all submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, to disable the buttons you would do

```
      $('#news').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      setTimeout($("$('#news').prop('disabled', '');" 30000);
      $('#sports').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      setTimeout($("$('#sports').prop('disabled', '');" 30000);
```

This could be modified to generically disable/enable all buttons on the page using

```
$("button, input[type='button']").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
setTimeout(function(){$("button, input[type='button']").prop('disabled', '');}, 30000);
```